# iOsS CNSetSupportedSSIDs equivalent for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, wifi, captivenetwork

iOS has a `CaptiveNetwork` programming interface with a function `CNSetSupportedSSIDs` which allows an app to register for specific SSIDs so that when a device associates to one of those SSSIDs and there is a captive portal, the app is called rather than the default web sheet. The app then has the responsibility to notify the OS when the user has authenticated to the Wi-Fi network.

Windows phone has the same behavior: also opens a web sheet when the phone associates to a captive network.

Is there an equivalent method for Windows Phone, for an app to register itself as the responsible for managing captive portals for specific SSIDs so that the app is opened when the captive portal is detected?

Answer (score 0):

First answer would be - **no, you can't bind to a specific SSID** from within the system itself (to launch the app, that is).

However, since a captive network most of the time redirects you to a specific URL, you could experiment launching apps via the associated app URI scheme. This will require that whatever network you're going to be managing actually has the capability to fetch an app URI instead of just the auth page.